# How can i keep the Jtable contents on the primary JFrame-1 after displaying it in new JFrame-2

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java, so any help is greatly appreciated...Thanks in advance.

JFrame-1 is split with JTable and JEditorPane. I create a new JFrame-2 after some events that occur on JFRame-1. JFrame2 also has a JSplitPane implemented( with 2 JTables(1 & 2) and 1 JEditorPane).
as soon as i copy the contents of JTabel from frame-1  to Jtabel2 in frame-2. the table disappears from the frame-1, How can i keep the contents of table in frame-1 as well as in frame-2.
This is the code i used to split the panes for Frame-2, and during debugging this is where the table(m_clsJTable) from Frame-1 clears.

```
JSplitPane top = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, new JScrollPane(clsNewJTable), new JScrollPane(m_clsJTable)); 
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, top, new JScrollPane(m_clsJEditorPane));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the same components in two different containers. If you want two containers to have the same view of some data, then you should create a separate view class for each, and have them both share the same model.

Comment: +1 This related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614457) also talks about how to synchronize scrolling.

Comment: Now i understand why it was clearing out the table from Frame-1. To separate view class for each- can you please explain this or point me to something that refers to this. Thank you!

Comment: @trashgod: Sorry, my example has one model for each view. @rkbdi: I think it would work with just one model in both views.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy- I am using defaultTableModel to create the JTable in Frame-1. will i still be able to create separate view class for each table? can you give me an example of 2 components (JTable) sharing the same defaultTableModel.

Comment: I got the table in Frame-2. Thanks!