# Connecting/linking JTable UIs

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have four JTables arranged in a 2x2 square. I want the columns and rows to be connected: when a column on one table is rearranged or resized (by the user or otherwise), I want the same things to happen to the table above or below (in real time); when rows or columns are sorted or highlighted, I want the highlighting to happen in the adjacent table, forming a continuous line of selection.
[image: Screenshot]

To the right, the numbered columns are the start of new tables (four tables in all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To synchronize scrolling, the vertical scroll bars of separate scroll panes can share a common  `BoundedRangeModel`. To synchronize selection, separate tables can share a common `ListSelectionModel`. The table models must be commensurate. There's an example showing two tables in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614457/230513).

Comment: @mKorbel: Ah, I see that `TableColumnModel` also has a `ListSelectionModel`.