# How do I make JScrollPane work properly with nested JTables?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

The problem I have is that when more rows are added to JTable (jtbls) the vertical scrollbar doesn't appear on my JScrollPane (outer).

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
JScrollPane outer = new JScrollPane(panel);

jtbls = new JTable[4];
for (int i = 0; i < jtbls.length; i++) {
    jtbls[i] = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
    jtbls[i].setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    jtbls[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

    JPanel inner = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    inner.add(jtbls[i], BorderLayout.CENTER);
    inner.add(jtbls[i].getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    inner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(outer.getWidth() / 4, 70));

    panel.add(inner);
}

add(outer);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set

```
inner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(outer.getWidth() / 4, 70));
```

So `inner` `JPanel` is "fine" with height above `70` and don't requests more space to the parent - `JPanel panel` which won't request more space to its parent - `JVieport`.

Also if you look at the source code of `JTable` - method `setFillsViewportHeight` is only applicable to the `javax.swing.JLayer`, `javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout`, `javax.swing.ViewportLayout` (look at invocations of `getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()`) - so this will work only when JTable is inside some viewport.

Answer (score 2):

You can set all but one of the scroll bars to `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` and set one to `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`. Then tie the scroll bar models together like @camickr showed me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614457/261156).